# Swift: Set several labels in container view to a ratio / percentage of the container

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

So I'm making an app programatically and I have a view which contains several labels. I want to evenly spread these labels in the container and I know this is possible by setting the height of each label to a percentage of the container.

For example if I have 4 labels, I could set each labels height to 25% of the height of the container they are in.

But the problem I am facing is that this is only possible (as far as I am aware) if the container has a declared constant height i.e.

```
myContainer.heightAnchor.contraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContainer.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
```

and done this way, everything works. But if setting the container height not as a constant but relative to something else then it doesn't work i.e.

```
myContainer.heightAnchor.contraint(equalTo: view.height, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContainer.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
//THIS DOES NOT WORK^
```

Does anyone know how to make it work, or another way to spread the labels and other elements evenly in the container (no storyboard!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview)?

I think all you need to do is create the stack view, pin it to its container view, and then add the labels. The good thing about it is that if you decide you want to add or remove a label, it just works, without having to adjust all of the label constraints.